# DAO & Business Logic

Tags: oop, design-patterns, database-design, dao

I was wondering about the amount of business logic that a DAO should deal with.

Ok, we all know that the purpose of DAOs is to encapsulate data access and hide all the informations about it as well as the implementation. Furthermore, the goal of DAOs is also to separate business logic from data access logic.

I would argue that a DAO *must* have some business logic in it, e.g. what if a business object could not be deleted or updated due to some requirements of the specific domain?
I guess that no one would implement the delete/update method for that DAO, and -for as I see it- this implies some knowledge of business logic.

Now, as you can imagine my question is more conceptual than practical, so it's useless advice to use an ORM as there is no concrete scenario of use.

The question is: how much business logic a DAO should handle, given any restriction on the manipulation of persistent data?

**Example:** 
`BusinessObject1` can be updated only once in its lifetime.
Supposed that we can easily know if it has already been updated, should the DAO throw an exception if we try to update `BusinessObject1` again?
Or it should detect nothing and this should be managed in the business layer?

Comment: Flagged, not because it's a bad question per se, but this probably isn't the best forum for it (seems more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Flagged as inappropriate on the basis that the question cannot be reasonably answered, "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". I did consider flagging as "not a question" because it's "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form". In any case, I don't think it can be edited into a more appropriate form, as it's a subjective question

Answer (score 11):

If you store your data in a database that has referential integrity rules, then your data layer has business rules in it.

This is the problem with all rules of thumb.  They work until they don't.  The point is not to avoid rules in your data layer, the point is to only put rules in the data layer that belong there.  For example, rules which enforce the *validity of stored data* belong in the data layer.  Rules that enforce how data is used *don't* belong in the data layer.

Comment: So in the example above the DAO should not care about who, when and how *accesses* data but should care about who/when/how *modifies* them?

Comment: @tmh - It's not so much about _read_ vs. _write_.  It's about what does the data look like by the time the transaction is committed.  So who/when data is modified is probably not a data layer issue at all.  This is not to say that RDBMS's don't have lots of functionality for this - they do.  However, rules about security are an application concern not a storage concern.  This distinction is logical.  Your physical implementation might leverage the security features of your RBDMS for practical reasons.

Comment: This was a long time ago and I came across this old answer and old comment and the landscape has shifted so I will add this further thought re: security features of RDBMS. Security should be multi-layered, so you should include security rules in your data layer because the rule of thumb "more security is better" outweighs the rule of thumb "don't put business logic in your data layer".

Answer (score 0):

You can define the restrictions in your `BusinessObject1` (eg: can only be updated 1 time), which your DAO will read. Then when you give to the DAO a modified object and tell him to persist that modification (update), the DAO will throw an exception.

I think this is how Doctrine (a Data Mapper ORM) works.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is that

> what if a business object could not be deleted or updated due to some
>   requirements of the specific domain?

I think its still a good idea to keep business logic separate from DAO because its the business that keeps changing most of the time. So if your requirement are to put business constraint while doing update n delete then Service layer should check this constraint. In this way you won't have to make any changes in DAO Layer.

Moreover, if in future you want to switch to another database then also you won't have to worry about the business logic as you only have to focus on db specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is partitioned into components that are independent of each other, you end up with a business component, a database component (possibly implemented as DAO), and a UI component typically. The business logic component is responsible for enforcing the core business rules behind the application; the database component, for accessing data and enforcing the rules for data manipulation; and finally, the UI component, for controlling the interaction with the user.

With such a design, there is no argument about whether the database component should contain logic: of course, it should. **It needs rules to govern how data is stored, retrieved and interpreted.** However, the kind of logic that it contains differs from the business logic or the UI logic. And, as already pointed out, the database component does not need to be a software component; it may consist of stored-procedures, functions and triggers in your database.

The bottom line is, feel free to put logic in your DAO but ensure that such logic pertains only to the operations that are relevant to data access. Similarly, it is fine to have logic in your UI component to drive the interaction with the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that the logic in the example above belong to data layer?

Comment: If your database component is used by only one application that requires this rule at the persistence level, then it is fine to implement that logic in the data layer as long as it is expressed in terms of columns and rows and not in terms of your business objects.